# TestNG: More than one @DataProvider for one @Test

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, testng, dataprovider

I'm using `TestNG` for `Eclipse`.

Is it possible to give two data providers step by step to the **same** test-function?

I could put both providers in one, but that is not what I want.

I need (not like in this example) to generate independently data.

```
@DataProvider(name = "dataSet1")
public Object[][] createDataX() {
    return new Object[][] { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 } };
}

@DataProvider(name = "dataSet2")
public Object[][] createDataY() {
    return new Object[][] { { 0, 0 }, { 3, 3 } };
}
```

I want to give both providers to the same test. Is this possible?

```
@Test(dataProvider = "dataSet1") // ??? and "dataSet2" ???
public void testThisFunction(int val1, int val2) {
    boolean solution = oracle(val1,val2);
    assert (solution);
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, but nothing stops you from merging these two data providers into one and specifying that one as your data provider:

```
public Object[][] dp1() {
  return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { "a", "b" },
      new Object[] { "c", "d" },
  };
}

public Object[][] dp2() {
  return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { "e", "f" },
      new Object[] { "g", "h" },
  };
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] dp() {
  List<Object[]> result = Lists.newArrayList();
  result.addAll(Arrays.asList(dp1()));
  result.addAll(Arrays.asList(dp2()));
  return result.toArray(new Object[result.size()][]);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
public void f(String a, String b) {
  System.out.println("f " + a + " " + b);
}
```

Comment: How does this approach sound to you  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/NutRyPEyqLI ?

Answer (score 3):

```java
@DataProvider
public Object[][] combinedDataProvider() {
    // Using stream to combine the two separate data providers.
    return Stream.of(dp1(), dp2())
                 .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                 .toArray(Object[][]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this answer:

[TestNG using multiple DataProviders with single Test method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549443/testng-using-multiple-dataproviders-with-single-test-method)

It is much cleaner and will work for more complex things.

Maybe someone will need it too, I rewrote this method `public static T[] concatAll(T[] first, T[]... rest)` in a different way:

```
public static Object[] concat(Object[] first, Object[] second) {
    Object[] result = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the working fix:**

```
@DataProvider(name = "requestValidator")
public Object[][] getRequestValidationMap() {
    ResponseEntity clientDetailsResponse = ResponseUtil.successResponse(HttpStatus.OK,
            clientDetailsEntityDao);
    ResponseEntity failureResponse = ResponseUtil.handleErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            ERRCONSTANT.CUSTOM_CODE.getErrorDescription(), ERRCONSTANT.CUSTOM_CODE.getCategory(),
            ERRCONSTANT.CUSTOM_CODE.getValue());
    return new Object[][] { { "client", clientDetailsResponse, 200, HttpServletResponse.SC_OK },
            { "error", failureResponse, 500, HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR } };
}
```

In the utility method

```
@Test(dataProvider = "requestValidator")
public void testMultipleArgs(String key, ResponseEntity requestValidatorResponse, int statusCodeExpected, int actualStatusCode) throws Exception {
        
}
```

Answer (score -10):

Yes,

You can write @Test(dataProvider="name_of_first_dataprovider,name_of_second_dataprovider")

Comment: If used like this, which data provider will be used for the test?

Comment: This would be nice, but does not work for me.  Which version of TestNG supports this dataProvider syntax?

Comment: This does not have any base, it does not work and it is not pointing to any documentation specifying such functionality